# Two Views/Controllers on one page?

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller

I'm new to CakePHP. So far I managed to build up some views, controllers and models. Here is my problem:

I have two tables:

- tea_types (A list of Teatypes with their steep-time)
- steep_logs (A history of Teas that has been steeped)

For each table I have a model, a view and a controller which is working fine.
Now I want to make a index.php where I want to combine three elements:

- TeaTypes (Actions: Edit, Delete, Add, Click to start a teatimer)
- TeaTimer (When passed a teatype a countdown should start - I want to do this with JavaScript)
- SteepLog (Every tea which was selected should be added to the table and the last 20 entries should be shown)

Every of these elements is ready, but not the combination of these in one view. Do I have to make an extra controller which combines these 3 elements? Is a controller without a model possible or wise?

The two controllers are also associated with each other:

- TeaType hasMany SteepLog
- SteepLog belongsTo TeaType

I think the solution is not so difficult, but I would know what the best-practice is.

Comment: You don't create a "combined" model/controller for this, but you have to [associate the models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html). Then, using [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior, you can retrieve all the data in one find.

Comment: That sounds good. I will have a look at these topics. Can you post it as an answer, then I will rate it an close the question if it works.

Comment: Start over with the blog tutorial. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html#getting-started Your table names are not following the conventions (not required but not good practice either) and the kind of questions you ask tell me that you don't really know how to use the framework and probably any other MVC framework as well.

Comment: Hi burzum, yes you're right. I'm new to MVC as well. Can you tell me how I should set up my tables? I thought that I did it like in a tutorial (plural etc). I think I only read the "blog tutorial" but not the further topics. I will catch this up. Thanks for any hint to improve me.

Comment: Do the tutorial again and pay attention this time. It tells you about conventions in the 3rd section ("Creating the Blog Database") of the *first* page. It links to this page that explains all conventions: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow conventions, your table names should be `tea_types` and `steep_logs`, the models for them should be `TeaType` and `SteepLog`, and the controllers should be `TeaTypesController` and `SteepLogsController`.

Without your schema, I can't tell you exactly how your model associations should be set by convention, but, logically I would think that `TeaType hasMany SteepLog` and `SteepLog belongsTo TeaType`. You can find out how to define your schema to fit the model association conventions from the blog tutorial or Cake book, that topic is too lengthy to summarize here.

Once your model associations are defined, you'll be able to find and manipulate both models from both controllers as needed.

Comment: Allright, I renamed my controllers, models, views and tables. I already had done the associations between TeaType and SteepLog. This works well with the scuffold. Next part would be to show the two views on one page.